# Display Gallio reports on CruiseControl.Net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, mbunit, gallio

I am setting up a CruiseControl.Net build server. My project compiles, and runs unit tests.

In my ccnet.config I have this:

```
<tasks>
    <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>C:\CCNet\Working\Website</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>Website.sln</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Debug /v:quiet /t:rebuild</buildArgs>
        <timeout>120</timeout>
    </msbuild>

    <exec>
        <executable>C:\Program Files\Gallio\bin\Gallio.Echo.exe</executable>
        <buildArgs>/rnf:Utilities-test-report /rt:Xml-Inline /v:Quiet /rd:C:\CCNet\Working\Website_tests C:\CCNet\Working\Website\Utilities.UnitTests\bin\Debug\Utilities.UnitTests.dll</buildArgs>
    </exec>
    <exec>
        <executable>C:\Program Files\Gallio\bin\Gallio.Echo.exe</executable>
        <buildArgs>/rnf:XMLGenerator-test-report /rt:Xml-Inline /v:Quiet /rd:C:\CCNet\Working\Website_tests C:\CCNet\Working\Website\XMLGenerator.UnitTests\bin\Debug\XMLGenerator.UnitTests.dll</buildArgs>
    </exec>
</tasks>
<publishers>
  <xmllogger logDir="C:\CCNet\Working\Website_logs" />
  <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds" cleanUpValue="20" />
  <merge>
    <files>
        <file>C:\CCNet\Working\Website_tests\Utilities-test-report.xml</file>
        <file>C:\CCNet\Working\Website_tests\XMLGenerator-test-report.xml</file>
    </files>
  </merge>
</publishers>
```

And in my dashboard.config I have this:

```
<buildPlugins>
  <buildReportBuildPlugin>
    <xslFileNames>
      <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\compile-msbuild.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\MBUnitDetails.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\MBUnitSummary.xsl</xslFile>
    </xslFileNames>
  </buildReportBuildPlugin>
  <buildLogBuildPlugin disableHighlightingWhenLogExceedsKB="50"/>
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="MSBuild Report" actionName="BuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\msbuild.xsl"></xslReportBuildPlugin>
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="MBUnit Test Report" actionName="GallioTestReport" xslFileName="xsl\MBUnitDetails.xsl" />
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="MBUnit Test Report (Condensed)" actionName="GallioTestReportCondensed" xslFileName="xsl\MBUnitSummary.xsl" />
  <gallioAttachmentBuildPlugin />
</buildPlugins>
```

In the dashboard, when I click on "MBUnit Test Report", I have a blank screen. When I click on test report (condensed), I see "not tests run". When I look at the build log, I see that the tests are ran :

```
<message>2 run, 2 passed, 0 failed, 0 inconclusive, 0 skipped</message>
```

The XML test files are generated in Website_tests.

What did I miss in order to display the test reports on the CCNet dashboard ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should merge files before `<xmllogger logDir="C:\CCNet\Working\Website_logs" />`in your config file

Comment: Nope, doesn't change a thing :(